# Trouble typing accented letters at the terminal prompt after launching Python

Tags: terminal, python

Edit:

Using Mac OSX 10.6, whether I use Terminal.app or iTerm.app, when I launch Python, I can no longer type accented letters (e.g.é or ä).

Any ideas?

ORIGINAL POST:
I am using iTerm 0.10.

I would like to type in a string with accented characters (e.g. é) but when I do so at the iTerm prompt, no character appears.

This does not occur in Terminal.

Could someone help me find out what the problem is, and eventually fix it?

EDIT: In Terminal.app, I can use accented characters. However, when I launch the Python 2.71 prompt, I can no longer type in accented characters.
When I quit python and return to the terminal prompt, I can again type accented characters.

In iTerm, although I quit Python and restarted iTerm, I cannot type in accented characters (I do not know if I could before).

Comment: The Python prompt? You mean the Python REPL running inside Terminal?

Comment: Does no character appear in the terminal at all?  Or only when output by a `print` statement?  (e.g. it appears when you enter it)  How are you inputting the characters?

Comment: @Ignacio: yes, inside the Terminal

Comment: @Patches: no that is not what I mean. If I try to type print "é", I can actually not type the letter é...

Comment: But you *can* type it at the *shell* prompt?

Comment: @Nicojo:  Does it work on the regular shell before you start Python?

Comment: @Dennis: I'll change the question. Indeed, at the shell prompt I cannot.

Comment: Do you have a keyboard that includes that character? Are you typing a dead-key sequence to get the character? What shell are you using? Are you using Terminal.app or another? Can you type the character in the GUI (apparently so)? If so, are you able to paste the character at the shell prompt?

Comment: @Dennis: for é, I don't have a dedicated key, but a combination. But for ä I have a dedicated key and the same problem. I cannot paste the character into the iTerm prompt.

Comment: @Patches: yes, I modified the question to take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a problem with Apple's shipped python, as indicated in the [Apple message boards.](https://discussions.apple.com/message/11569875#11569875)

Comment: Thanks for the link! This is indeed exactly my problem: good to know I'm not crazy :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8 in your iTerm session.
[Instructions and helpful thread](http://blog.ndrix.com/2007/12/iterm-utf-8.html).

I used to have to do this on old version, I'm not sure if it's default in the newer ones as I haven't used it in some time.

EDIT: I also found [this](http://www.hafenscher.net/wiki/index.php?page=enable_real_UTF-8_support_in_iTerm) that may be of some help to you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't help. I first followed the second link, created a .profile file and restarted iTerm. Then I checked the encoding and it is UTF-8. But I still cannot type é in iTerm. Neither can I do so in Terminal.app when using Python. Any other idea?

Comment: What's the value of LC_CTYPE? iTerm/iTerm2 won't load a .profile or .bash_profile if your profile/bookmark doesn't specify to use your home directory. In that case, put it in .bashrc.

Comment: @George: Sorry for the late reply; been a bit worried about the situation in Japan, where I currently live. I the LC_CTYPE is UTF-8 in Terminal.app and USA ASCII in iTerm, that is before starting Python (once python launched, locale charmap doesn't work). I've added the .bashrc. This solves the problem with iTerm. But the problem within the python prompt remains... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Python problem appears to be a bug/misfeature in Apple's `editline` library; looks like it's taking `Option` as the old Unixy `Meta` behavior, where it sets the high bit on the next character.  I don't think this is fixable without replacing Python, unfortunately, unless you want to disable line editing entirely.  (And MacPorts' Python does the same thing.)

If you *do* want to disable line editing, try this.

```
$ echo 'python: edit off' >> ~/.editrc
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand what you mean: that would be the case if I actually needed to use the Option key, right? But I'm using a Swedish and a Japanese keyboard. The ä is a dedicated key for instance on the swedish keyboard. Sorry if I'm totally misunderstanding... Could you please clarify?

Comment: That might make things worse; I don't know how `editline` deals with that, but probably poorly (it dates from back before anyone really cared about internationalization).  The `edit off` thing may still help, though.

Comment: sorry, didn't do anything... any other idea?